# How to change the displayed text in label (for Internationalization)

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html file that contains something like this

```
> <label id="remem" for"remem"><input type"checkbox"
> name="remem"/>Test</label>
```

now Im dealing with i18n and working on translating these words. And what I need to do is Translate the word Test into a different language.

How do I change the label (in my example.."Test" ) programmatically?? What attribute should I deal with?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you expect to automatically translate programmatically, or just update the word 'test' to another word?

Comment: Are you sure you want to do localization in JavaScript? Normally, it is done (and should be done) server-side.

Comment: The markup is seriously erroneous. Please show the actual markup you have to work with, and specify whether the markup is given (cannot be changed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the text inside a `<span>` tag with `id`

```
> <label id="remem" for"remem"><input type"checkbox"
> name="remem"/><span id="rememText">Test</span></label>
```

Then you can use javascript to manipulate the text.

```
document.getElementById("rememText").innerHTML = "another language";
```

Answer (score 1):

@SajithNair's answer certainly works, and for small projects it is quite workable.

For large projects, however, you might find that you need something a bit more organized.

## Choice 1

Letting server-side code handle it.

Depending on your server-side framework, this may be the best solution.

## Choice 2

Letting a client-side framework handle it.

If you are using something like `Knockout`, it is a simple matter to decorate your labels with the right bindings and letting Knockout magic happen.

```
<label for="myfield">
  <span data-bind="html: resources.myFieldLabelText"></span>
  <input id="myfield" name="myfield">
</label>
```

## Choice 3

If you are not using Knockout, or you decide that making all of your resources observable is too much of a hit, using data-attributes and  then swapping out text that way can work.

```
<label for="myfield">
  <span data-label-resource="myfieldResourceKey"></span>
  <input id="myfield" name="myfield">
</label>
```

jQuery/sizzle has a nice engine to handle finding things by `data-*`, otherwise you can drop back to `querySelectorAll`.  Failing that and you are supporting an ANCIENT browser, you can walk the DOM.

The advantage of using the resource keys like this, rather than doing things ad-hoc on a per-field basis, is that if you re-use a value (say, entry or display, or you use it on multiple pages) you only have one resource that needs translated, as opposed to multiple instances.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 <span id="rememText">Test</span>

 $("#rememText").innerHtml("string text");
```

or

```
<span id="rememText">Test</span>
$("#rememText").val("string text");
```